# How to make a section sticky using Tailwind CSS utility classes

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

In my Next.js web app, I have a page as shown below:

[image]

I want to make the section (wrapped in `<aside>` tag) highlighted in blue sticky, so that when I scroll it stays where it is and only the main section (the section containing the chart) scrolls.

Here is the `layout.tsx` file:

```
import { dashboardConfig } from "@/config/dashboard";
import { MainNav } from "@/components/nav/main-nav";
import { DashboardNav } from "@/components/nav/dashboard-nav";

interface DashboardLayoutProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

export default async function DashboardLayout({
  children,
}: DashboardLayoutProps) {
  return (
    <div className="flex min-h-dvh flex-col relative">
      <header className="container z-40 bg-background">
        <MainNav />
      </header>
      <div className="container grid flex-1 gap-12 md:grid-cols-[200px_1fr] mt-32 mb-12 relative">
        <aside className="hidden w-[200px] flex-col md:flex sticky top-0">
          <DashboardNav items={dashboardConfig.sidebarNav} />
        </aside>
        <main className="flex w-full flex-1 flex-col overflow-hidden">
          {children}
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Notice that I have applied classes `sticky` and `top-0` to the section I want to have the position sticky. But it's not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider applying `align-self: start` via `self-start` to the sticky element. By default, it would have `align-self: stretch` which would make it the full height of its parent grid element, thus no sticky effect is observed. By applying `align-self: start`, it will only be as tall as its content, allowing a sticky effect to be observed if there is vertical free space.

```js
const dashboardConfig = { sidebarNav: '' };
const MainNav = () => 'MainNav';
const DashboardNav = () => 'DashboardNav';

function DashboardLayout({
  children,
}) {
  return (
    <div className="flex min-h-dvh flex-col relative">
      <header className="container z-40 bg-background">
        <MainNav />
      </header>
      <div className="container grid flex-1 gap-12 md:grid-cols-[200px_1fr] mt-32 mb-12 relative">
        <aside className="hidden w-[200px] flex-col md:flex sticky top-0 self-start">
          <DashboardNav items={dashboardConfig.sidebarNav} />
        </aside>
        <main className="flex w-full flex-1 flex-col overflow-hidden">
          {children}
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <DashboardLayout>
      <div class="h-[200vh]"></div>
    </DashboardLayout>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```